# Speeding up GDAL gridding process

Tags: gdal, performance, gdal-grid

I have a shapefile containing 28 915 413 points.

I am trying to grid it using the minimum method and create a raster.

The survey was at 0.5 m, so I have set this as the radius and the output file resolution in the hope of achieving the most accurate results.

```
gdal_grid -zfield Z -a minimum:radius1=0.5:radius2=0.5:angle=0.0:min_points=0:nodata=0.0 -ot Float32 -of GTiff -txe 317044 322287 -tye 681703 685053 -tr 0.5 0.5 "C:/test/input_shapefile.shp" C:/test/output_raster.tif
```

However, the above code is taking FOREVER to grid, and by forever I mean it has been over an hour running with 0% complete.

Is there any way to quicken the process, as my laptop is now overheating due to the strain

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You appear to have created three accounts which inevitably leads to a frustrating experience for you, potential answerers and reviewers so please follow [these instructions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) ASAP to merge your accounts.

Comment: are you sure your points aren't already on a grid? in R use raster::rasterFromXYX(x) with the obvious matrix-like x  - your target extents imply 70256200 grid points, so possibly you actually have values in grid already - that R code won't take any time to run, and if just want to index point-value to cell it's also very fast (not sure the analogous GDAL commands for that simpler task)

Comment: @mdsumner I wouldn't be best familiar with this method. Perhaps you could help assist me if possible?

Comment: sure got a reprex?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should wait some time. There seems to be this pull request in a queue https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/pull/5397 with a promising title:

> ADD facility to search points included in search ellipse for
> GDALDataMetrics (minimum, maximum, range, count, average_distance,
> average_distance_pts) in the already implemented quadtree data
> structure.